# nullpointer on intent android

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am getting `NullPointerException` on Intent. I am coming to the same activity from two different activities. And my code is like:

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action").equals("yes"){   // NULLPOINTER HERE

 //Some code

 }
 else if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action").equals("completed"){

 // Some code

 }
```

When I am sending "completed" in putExtra then it shows error, when I send "yes", it works fine.

Comment: check `getIntent().getStringExtra("action")!=null`

Comment: Check if you are using extra variable as "action" in both the places.

Comment: You are missing closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action")!=null)
{
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action").equals("yes")){  

 //Some code

 }
 else if(getIntent().getStringExtra("action").equals("completed")){

 // Some code

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

Add this inside your Oncreate

```
String yourvalue;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     yourvalue = extras.getString("STRINGVALUE");

  }
```

//Use anywhere

```
  if(yourvalue.equals(""))
        {
        //your value is empty
        }
        else
        {
        if(yourvalue.equals("yes"))
        {  

         //Some code

         }
         else if(yourvalue.equals("completed"))
        {

         }

        }
```

check your putextra data is sending to next intent or not

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),newAct.class);                 
    intent.putExtra("STRINGVALUE", value);
     startActivity(intent);
```